# ..../PM/src/pm3D.so: invalid ELF header

Tags: python, linux, machine-learning

I am getting this error when I am trying to run my python file. Apparently one of the files consists of import pm3D. I have a pm3D.so file but constantly getting this error. I am trying to run this on linux server with python version 3.7

Answer (score 1):

It means `pm3D` is not a valid file. It's either missing (from the path you specified), corrupted, or misnamed somewhere.